# c++ char array out of scope or not?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, stl

I have a method that requires a `const char` pointer as input (not null terminated). This is a requirement of a library (TinyXML) I'm using in my project. I get the input for this method from  a `string.c_str()` method call.

Does this `char` pointer need to be deleted? The string goes out of scope immediately after the call completes; so the string should delete it with its destructor call, correct?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which method is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The char array returned by `string.c_str()` is null terminated. <strike>If tinyXML's function takes a not null terminated char* buffer, then your probably gonna get some unexpected behaviour.</strike>

> `const char* c_str ( ) const;`
>
> Get C string equivalent
>
> Generates a null-terminated sequence
>   of characters (c-string) with the same
>   content as the string object and
>   returns it as a pointer to an array of
>   characters.
>
> A terminating null character is
>   automatically appended.

No, it does not need to be released. String's destructor does that for you.

> The returned array points to an
>   internal location with the required
>   storage space for this sequence of
>   characters plus its terminating
>   null-character, but the values in this
>   array should not be modified in the
>   program and are only granted to remain
>   unchanged until the next call to a
>   non-constant member function of the
>   string object.

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: I doubt tiny XML's function would barf at a null terminated char*. After all, it's not as though the size can be determined just from the pointer. Also, if you have an arbitrary char*, it's possible the memory right after the memory you allocated has a null character. I have a feeling that Jack BeNimble was just trying to emphasize that the argument did not have to be a typical c string. (Ps - this is a different Tom from the poster :-) )

Comment: Lol, got very confused for a second or two :-) I was here first !!!

It was strange for me too the fact that a method asks for a "not null terminated char pointer", that's why i asked for the name of Tiny xml's method. (this is Tom, the poster.)

Comment: Tom (the poster): Please edit your answer to remove the erroneous stuff about nul terminated strings.  Then Tom (the different) can delete his comment, you can yours, and I can mine.

Answer (score 10):

Do not delete the memory you get from std::string::c_str. The string is responsible for that (and it is entirely possible it gave you a pointer to its internal buffer, so if you deleted it, that would be a bad thing (tm)).

Answer (score 4):

On another note,
If you don't need to char pointer to be null terminated then you're better off to used `str.data()` rather than `str.c_str()`. The difference is that `.data()` doesn't grantee that what you get is going to be null terminated. This is useful if the your string just happens to occupy the entire length of the internal buffer allocated by `string`. In this case, calling `.c_str()` would force `string` to reallocate the date to a new bigger buffer, ones that contains enough space to add the `'\0'` in the end.

In any rate, ofcourse you shouldn't delete the pointer returned. `string` will take care of that.

Comment: +1 because I like your point that you can save reallocation by calling .data(). I never realized that existed. I think I must have assumed that std::string always kept a null terminator in place for the call to c_str(). Good to know :-).

Answer (score 1):

`std::string.c_str()` returns a pointer to a null terminated string. The actual array of characters is still owned by the `std::string` object, and it is valid as long as:

1. The `std::string` object is valid, and
2. No calls to non-const member functions on the `std::string` object are made (i.e. modifying the string invalidates any previous C-style string pointed to).

It's up to the string object itself to allocate and release the null terminated array-of-char it returns to you.

You can always use a null-terminated string as a non-null-terminated string. After all, an NTS is just a non-NTS with an extra zero at the end. As long as the string is correctly terminated as the function expects, it'll never see the "extra" null.

Comment: Thanks Wuggy. I just posted that last point you made as a comment to (other) Tom's post.